# Excel: Return all values in a column if a cell matches the column name

Tags: excel, return-value

Just a quick question:

How can I return all values in a column if a cell matches the column name in another workbook?

So here is what I am trying to do:

There are two workbooks "wb1" and "wb2". So in wb2 there are 1000 columns, and the 1st row in each column is the product ID. And in each column there are a few hundred rows of sales numbers.

What I am trying to do is that, in wb1, in the cell A1, I enter a product ID. And hopefully in that column in wb1, it will return all the sales numbers from wb2 where the product ID in wb1 matches the name in wb2.

Is there anyway that I can do this?

Many tnanks guys.

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

qucik solutions can be greatly  improved
I will assume you have wb1 open since that is where you put your value

```
private Sub SUBNAME()
dim prodID As String sales As Range

Workbooks.open("location of file C:\Desktop\wb2.xls")

Workbooks("wb1.xls").activate

prodID = Range("a1").value

Workbooks("wb2.xls").activate
Range("a1").select 

Selection.Find(What:=prodID, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate


sales = ActiveCell.Column

Columns(sales).copy

Workbooks("wb1.xls").activate

Columns("B").select
Selection.Insert shift:=xlRight
```

This code is weak, you need to always enter the Product ID to wb1 range a1. In wb2 if there are multiple products with the same name only the first will be copied and printed to wb1. You can either run this maro with the macro diaolog box or you can add a command button to wb1 and click it. You would also be able to do this with a event handler (Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target, As Range)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. Just make sure that you have enough lines to cover the lengthiest case (largest number of rows).

In Wb1, cell A2 and then drag down:

```
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP([Wb1]Sheet1!$A$1, [Wb2]Sheet2!$A$1:$BBB2, ROW(), 0), "")
```

Let's explain this. HLOOKUP does a horizontal lookup for the value provided in the first parameter. It searches in the first row of the range provided as its second parameter. The third one is the number of the row to be returned relative to the start of the range in parameter 2, 1 being the first row. Finally, 0 specifies that you want an exact match. If you specify 1 as the last parameter it will also accept different cases as valid.

Notice that I haven't locked the last row of the second parameter so that the range grows as you drag the formula.

This will not be a solution as "clean" as VBA could do (you need to make sure that you have dragged your formula far enough to get all rows) but it will be *much* simpler and that is something I like to go for.

Edit: Also added IFERROR() to removed `#N/A`s in order to be able to do calculations.